# ACER ASPIRE V3-571G-9435 Fan not kicking in leading to overclocking

Tags: cpu, fan, nvidia-geforce, overheating

This laptop has always had this problem. The temperatures kick up to the thermal ceiling of 99 °C for the CPU (i7-3610QM) and 94 °C for the GPU (GT 640M). Problem is, the FAN doesn't give a damn. It's actually QUIETER when the temperatures are that high than when it's at 60 °C or so. I figured it was a problem with the BIOS, so I updated that; no change. So maybe it was a problem with Windows? Nope; same result on gaming with Ubuntu.

The major problem of this, is that after gaming for ten minutes, the CPU throttles itself to 1197 MHz (as opposed to 3193), and the GPU goes down to 135 MHz (as opposed to 843 MHz).

The problem is that the fan won't kick in like I know it can,
because when the laptop is in POST, like at BIOS setup,
the fan is so loud it's like a vacuum cleaner! 
I don't really care about noise, so I'd love to have the fan like that all the time as long as the temperatures don't fly through the roof...

So, things I've tried so far, to avoid possible duplicate answers.

- Checked for dust: It's been this way since the laptop was new, and I've since then taken it apart. No dust buildup.
- Background stuff running?: No; problem persists across OS'es, and it happens while gaming anyways.
- Manually underclocking both CPU/GPU:
  Using Windows, I can force the CPU to stay at 1.1 GHz,
  but the temperature STILL easily hits 99 °C after five minutes of gaming.
- Contacted Acer support?: No help at all. They told me to update and reset the BIOS, which I have done multiple times. There are only about 6 changeable things anyway, none of which should affect the FAN control.
- Third party fan control program?: None detect the fan.

So, I'm screwed until I can afford to replace this laptop, but I am very satisfied with performance in games... Whenever the CPU/GPU aren't being throttled.

Anyone that can offer advice to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have entered the BIOS and you could find nothing that adjusted the temp. that can get the fan kicked into a higher RPM? If there is anything in the BIOS that remotely looks like it affects the fan and it is set to AUTO, change it to a setting that you can manipulate the fan speed.

Comment: Same problem here whith my laptop: Acer Aspire V3-571G with Core i7 3632QM

Comment: Hello, its been 7 years and I have gotten rid of that laptop long ago. I solved the problem though. Using an app called ECCFANCONTROL. Through a complicated process. You have to rewrite the ECC programming in your bios. This is very dangerous and can lead to a bricked system. For some reason, my ECC was rewritten with all 00s. So I was able to copy the ecc data codes from another same laptop and it worked!.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 and probably other versions, there exists a "System Cooling Policy" setting hidden inside the advanced energy options.  Make sure it is set to "active", this results in higher fan speeds, instead of reducing the CPU speed.

You can find this option, by visiting the Energy settings -> advanced energy settings -> processor.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cool 'n quiet is off if you have that option in your bios. That will rate limit the fan speed and is often a default setting in BIOS/ UEFI BIOS.

Also, I agree with niro...if you have installed any packages from nvidia, it would be worth removing them and possibly reinstalling any acer drivers for nvidia off of their support site.